# plupload multiple drop_elements

Tags: jquery, plupload

I am using Plupload on a page that will have multiple drop_elements as well as browse buttons. My question is, by default with plupload you can define an element for both the drop_element and browse_button, from what i've read and tried it only accepts 1 element which happens to be an ID of that element.

I am needing to somehow extend this, so that I can define an array of id's or change it to be a class instead of an id.

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes : 'gears,html5,flash,silverlight,browserplus',
        browse_button : **['ele_id1', 'ele_id2']**,
        drop_element : **['dropzone_id1', 'dropzone_id2']**,
        max_file_size : '200mb',
        url: '//senditfrom.me/fileupload/upload/do_upload',
        flash_swf_url: '//senditfrom.me/fileupload/js/plupload.flash.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: '//senditfrom.me/fileupload/js/plupload.silverlight.xap',

        resize : {width : 320, height : 240, quality : 90}
    });
```

Is this possible? has anyone found a way around just being able to have 1 element defined?

Comment: I did manage to have 2 different drop_elements and browse_buttons however I had to create a new uploader.. and bind all buttons to interact with both uploader and uploader2

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question but I came across the problem of having 2 browse_buttons and found a way to solve it which I'd like to share here.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="uploader">
    <input type="button" class="pickfiles" id="0" value="Select 1"/>
    <input type="button" class="pickfiles" id="1" value="Select 2"/>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
var uploader = new plupload.Uploader(
    {
        browse_button : '0',
        container : 'uploader',
    });

$('.pickfiles').mouseenter(function()
{
    uploader.settings.browse_button = $(this).attr('id'); //Assign the ID of the pickfiles button to pluploads browse_button
    uploader.refresh();
});
```

See the below jsfiddle for details.

http://jsfiddle.net/wLMNB/

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if the plugin has changed since David Healey posted his answer but I found that his answer works with a small modification.

His section:

```
$('.pickfiles').mouseenter(function()
{
    uploader.settings.browse_button = $(this).attr('id'); //Assign the ID of the pickfiles button to pluploads browse_button
    uploader.refresh();
});
```

Should be changed to:

```
$('.pickfiles').mouseenter(function () {
            uploader.setOption("browse_button", $(this).attr('id')); //Assign the ID of the pickfiles button to pluploads browse_button
        });
```

And presto it works!

Answer (score 2):

you may have to hack the plugin. in plugin they have used getElementById(browse_button) you can try changing it to use class instead. i have not tried this but it may work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I can manage to change that... you'd there would be an easier way.